# Is Google Apps for Work part of the Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm currently working on a assay for a school project about Google Services.
The question is not programming related, but I hope you guys could help me out.

I've done some research and a little bit of digging on the Google Cloud Platform and Google Apps for Work, but before I start to make wrong assumptions in my assay, I was hoping if you could say wether I'm right or wrong.

Is Google Apps for Work part of the Google Cloud Platform? Or is it a whole seperate service?

I couldn't find any connections between the two, but shouldn't Google Apps for Work a service of te Google Cloud Platform?

Thanks in advance!
Tristan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short**: No it's not part of Google Cloud platform.

**Long**: Google Apps for Work contains products such as Gmail, Google Drive, Google Hangouts, Google Calendar, and Google Docs. You will probaby be familiar with at least some of those. These can all be used by individuals at home, but if used in the 'for work'-context they offer some extra features such as custom domains and support. While these are all running in the cloud, they are not technically part of Google Cloud platform.

Google Apps for Work can be seen as a **SaaS**-product ([Software as a service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)), while Google Cloud platform is more of a **PaaS**-product ([Platform as a Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service)). While Apps for work lets you **use the software written by Google** (Gmail, docs,...), Google Cloud Platform allows developers **write custom applications** which run on the Google cloud.

Applications written on Google Cloud Platform can however be used together with the Apps for Work part. For example you could use your Apps for Work account to log in to a custom application written on GCP, or you could access your emails or from within your custom application stuff like that.

Small note, GCP also contains stuff like Google Compute Engine, which is more of a IaaS (Infrastructure as a service). However this will still be used for custom development by the user, but it gives the developer more freedom.

Comment: Thanks!
Your answer is exactly what I needed.